# Is there difference `yarn dev` and `yarn run dev`?

Tags: yarnpkg

To run the local server for development I normally use `yarn run dev`.

But it seems `yarn dev` provides same function. Is this command just a short alias for `yarn run dev`?

I couldn't find info for `yarn dev` in [documents](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can leave out run from this command.
Basically, not only dev command, you can directly use any scripts by name without keyword run. 
So, yarn dev and yarn run dev  both do the same.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run/

> It’s also possible to leave out the run in this command, each script can be executed with its name

And a similar example is given for yarn 2

https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run

> Same thing, but without the "run" keyword :

Comment: It also says `Note that built-in cli commands will have preference over your scripts, so you shouldn’t always rely on this shortcut in other scripts.` So most of the time it's okay but these 2 are always the same.